# How to escape HTML for use in JavaScript strings?

Tags: javascript, html, string, escaping, special-characters

Basically, I want to do this:

```
const html = "HTML source code";
```

HTML source code might contain new line characters, tabs, quotes...anything that's valid HTML. The value of `html` variable is then used to create a valid html page using JavaScript like this:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = unescape(html);
```

I tried several things like replacing quotes (single or double), replacing new line characters and wrapping the html inside `` to make template literals...but all seem to fail for (source code of) certain webpages.

E.g.:

```
//fails
const html = `HTML here`;
document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;
```

..and

Comment: Have you tried String.raw ?

Comment: Can you give some examples of things that fail?

Comment: @IanShields If I go with template literals like this `HTML source`, it works for most pages but sometimes some part of the source code is rendered as raw text. Okay, SO is interpreting a pair of ` as code.

Comment: If a string literal contains invalid characters, then you can't repair it by doing a `replace()` call on it. You need to fix whatever creates the source code.

Comment: `const html = "<b>HTML source code\n test</b>"; document.documentElement.innerHTML = html;` works fine. In html new line characters `\n` won't be interpreted you have to use `<br>`

Comment: doesn't it fail for this `const html = "<b>HTML " source code\n test</b>";`

Comment: Yes, that should fail because the surrounding and inner quotes don't match. If you want to use quotes inside a string than they shouldn't match the quotes surrounding/outer string. E.g. `const html = "<b>HTML 'source code'\n test</b>"; ` or `const html = '<b>HTML "source code"\n test</b>'; `

Comment: This will break, then: `const html = "<script> const someVar = 'a string "
 so long'</script>"`

Comment: Please let me know if I am wrong. I'm just too bad with strings.

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't work because of the `"` quote marks. In addition, because of the `</script>` tag as HTML will interpret this as the end of the script element. Instead, for the script tag you have to add an "\" backlash so it's `</\script>` for other HTML tags it should not be a huge problem. For further information specifically on JavaScript strings look at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, this should help you out:

```js
const html = "<p><h2>I'm a headline!</h2>I'm some text!</p>";
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

---

If your HTML code uses quotes (for ids, classes, etc.), you could use single quotes:

```js
const html = '<div id="someDiv"><img src="https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tree"></div>';
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

---

If your code has e. g. new lines, escape them with `\n` or just delete them so your string fits in one single line:

```js
const html = "<p>\n<h2>Headline!</h2\n</p>";
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Beware: `\n` != `<br>`!

---

If you want to put your code-string together by adding two or more variables, do this:

```js
const htmlPart1 = "<p><h2>";
const htmlPart2 = "Heading!</h2></p>";

document.body.innerHTML = htmlPart1 + htmlPart2;
```

---

If you want to insert a `script` tag containing some JS, I'm afraid you can't do that. I tried it myself a lot while writing this answer, and I didn't find any solution.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.